# Difference between indexing(@index) and unique constraints in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I have a table it contains the following unique constraint:
`@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"col1", "col2","col3"}))`

When user tries to make an entry in db, I have to make db call first whether that  entry is already exists or not. So i have to do so many lookups.
I want to know the difference between unique constraint and index.
If i use `@index` means will it make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

**@UniqueConstraint**
Assume that i has a table named student with three columns id,name,class. I want to create a unique constraint by using id,name,class. unique constraint make sure all values in a column is unique.

@index
Whenever u want do too many Db operations we can use the @index annotation. This annotation is used to execute db queries fast.